# Visualize Pascal's triangle and other triangle shaped lists

Tags: graphics, data-structures

How can Pascal's triangle be visualised like this in Mathematica?
[image]

Or more generally, how can a 'triangular' list like

```
{{1},{1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}}
```

be visualized in this way.

Also I would like to do 'conditional things' like colouring the number two red.

Comment: We're out of red. Can we make it blue, please?

Comment: But should Pascal's triangle be displayed like that, with each row center-aligned -- or would it be better to have all the rows left-aligned? In the latter form, it's often easier to calculate with it. That's an old insight by Ken Iverson; see, e.g.: http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Essays/Pascal's%20Triangle

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is another way:

```
pascalTriangle[n_] := 
  NestList[{1, Sequence @@ Plus @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1], 1} &, {1}, 
   n - 1];

Column[Grid[{#}, ItemSize -> 3] & /@ (pascalTriangle[7] /. 
    x_Integer :> 
     Text[Style[x, Large, If[x == 2, Red, Black]]]), Center]
```

[image]

Answer (score 29):

To address your question about visualizing a triangular list, let's use the following list:

```
t = Table[Binomial[n, k], {n, 0, 8}, {k, 0, n}]

(*out *)
{{1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 3, 1}, {1, 4, 6, 4, 1}, {1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1}, 
 {1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1}, {1, 7, 21, 35, 35, 21, 7, 1}, {1, 8, 28, 56, 70, 56, 28, 8, 1}}
```

You can format the list as a matrix:

```
MatrixForm[t]
```

[image: matrix]

---

You can insert tabs between the items and print each row, literally as a `Row`, in a grid.

```
{Row[#, "\t"]} & /@ t // Grid
```

[image: tabs]

By using `Row`, we are sending `Grid` one item for each gridrow.  (If `Row` were not employed, `Grid` would treat each item of a sublist as requiring its own column. That will lead to a triangle skewed from left to right. )

---

Here are a couple of ideas on how to style the `2` as large and red.  The following will make any entry of `2` red (it will not color the 2 in `20`).

```
t1 = Table[Binomial[n, k], {n, 0, 8}, {k, 0, n}] /. {2 -> Style[2, Red, 18]}
```

[image: out red]

You may then format `t1` as a matrix or as a grid.

---

The following makes the `2` in the center of a sublist with 3 elements red.  It's not necessary to do this because `2` only shows up once in Pascal's triangle. But you get the idea...

```
t2 = Table[Binomial[n, k], {n, 0, 8}, {k, 0, n}] /. {a_, 2, c_} :> {a, Style[2, Red, 18], c}
```

Comment: Thank you. From your examples I learned a lot.

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 27):

My modest attempt:

```
With[{n = 7},
     Graphics[Table[Text[Style[Binomial[n - j, n - i], Large], {Sqrt[3] (i - j/2), 3 j/2}],
                    {i, n}, {j, i}]]]
```

[image: Pascal's triangle]

---

Here's a more general function:

```
triangularArrayLayout[triArray_List, opts___] := Module[{n = Length[triArray]}, 
  Graphics[MapIndexed[
         Text[Style[#1, Large], {Sqrt[3] (n - 1 + #2.{-1, 2}), 3 (n - First[#2] + 1)}/2] &,
           triArray, {2}], opts]]
```

Use it on the Stirling subset numbers $\left\{{n \atop k}\right\}$:

```
triangularArrayLayout[Table[StirlingS2[n, k], {n, 0, 5}, {k, 0, n}]]
```

[image: Stirling subset triangle]

Comment: How can I control the horizontal spacing between elements within a row here? (I tried using this method for something else and everything worked fine except the entries are quite cramped).

Comment: @John, tweaking `ImageSize` might help here.

Answer (score 17):

This is my favorite way to draw Pascal's triangle.

```
pt = NestList[{0, ##} + {##, 0} & @@ # &, {1}, #] &;

ptform[pt : {_List ..}] := 
 With[{n = Length@Last@pt, long = Max@Map[StringLength@ToString@# &, pt, {2}]}, 
  Graphics[MapIndexed[Text[#, {#2 - #/2, -#} & @@ #2] &, pt, {2}], 
   PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 0.7, 
   BaseStyle -> FontSize -> Scaled[1.5/(n long)]]]
```

The advantage here is that the produced graphic is resizable, and the font size is automatically selected.  Elements can be styled either with `/.` or `MapAt`.

```
pt@7 /. 2 -> Style[2, Red] // ptform
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
MapAt[Style[#, Red] &, pt@11, {{5, 3}, {6, 4}, {7, 1}}] // ptform
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 14):

I like the following way of visualizing the Pascal triangle:

```
PascalTriangleForm[li : {{_}, {_, _}, __List}] /; 
   (Length /@ li) == Range[Length[li]] :=   
 Grid[SparseArray[Thread[
    Level[Table[Table[{i, n + 1 - i}, {i, 1, n}], {n,Length[li]}], {2}] -> 
    Level[li, {2}]
 ], Automatic, ""]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any particular reason you like this representation?

Comment: @sjdh This is the way the Pascal triangle was first historically arranged. I have seen it in [this book](http://www.amazon.com/History-Mathematical-Statistics-1750-1930/dp/0471179124) by Hald.

Comment: I like this as well, easier to store in a grid.

Answer (score 6):

Intuitive noobish way to program this.

```
Table[CoefficientList[(x + 1)^i, x], {i, 0, 10}]
```

I hope this helps other beginners :)

use `MatrixForm` to visualise!
 [image]

Answer (score 6):

Another way is to use `CellularAutomaton`:

```
pascal = CellularAutomaton[{#.{1, 0, 1} &, {}, 1}, {{1}, 0}, 6];

Text[Grid[pascal /. {0 -> ""}, ItemSize -> {1.5, 1.5}, Spacings -> {0, 0}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is actually demonstrated on the [Wolfram Demonstrations Project pages](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PascalsTriangle/). Download the notebook!

Comment: @sjdh and just so you know: I didn't happen to know that it was part of the Wolfram Demonstrations. I used a [search engine](http://www.google.com/) to find that out.

Comment: Also discussed [here](http://thinkmeta.wordpress.com/category/mathematica/), if you scroll down (with a nice Manipulate).

Comment: You noticed, no doubt, that the code makes use of `CellularAutomaton`.

Comment: @F'x This Wolfram demonstration I have seen before, I'm sure there are simpler ways to draw Pascal's triangle that can be used to visualise any list with a triangle shape.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to generate Pascal's triangle is to use a kind of cellular automaton on a rectangular grid, starting with a zero grid with one $1$ at the top and the rule at each step makes a zero cell into a sum of its above diagonal neighbors.

The code is:

```
Nm=12;
C1=Table[0,{j,1,Nm},{k,1,2Nm}];
C1[[1,Nm]]=1;
C2=C1;
Do[Do[If[C2[[j,k]]==0,C2[[j,k]]=C1[[j-1,k+1]]+C1[[j-1,k-1]]],{j,2,Nm-1},{k,2,2Nm-1}];
C1=C2,{n,1,Nm}]
Print[Grid[Table[If[C2[[j,k]]==0," ",C2[[j,k]]],{j,1,Nm},{k,1,2Nm}]]]
```

The result is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
f[m_, k_] := If[Binomial[m, k] != 0, Binomial[m, k], ""]

pascal[n_] := Grid[Table[f[m, k], {m, 0, n}, {k, 0, n}]]
```

[image]

Comment: It is not really different from: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9963/5478, is it?

Comment: No it's not, just slightly different look