# Add arrows over matrix

Tags: graphics, output-formatting, grid-layouts

## How can I plot this graph

---

```
g1 = Table[x[i, j], {i, 5}, {j, 5}] // Grid;

Rasterize@g1
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

I added these arrows by <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>'s graphics tool.

This way maybe hard to adjust the positions of x and arrows to a precise consistent level, also we need make arrows parallel..

One way is define the coordinates of x and then use `Graphics` to add `Text` and  `Arrow.`.

Any other good methods/choices?

I think this could be one general job, because sometimes we may add other objects/marks over matrix. This is the diagonal of Fibonacci Numbers over [Pascal Triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this a one time only task?

Comment: @belisarius I think this could be one general job, because sometimes we may add other objects/marks over matrix. This is  the diagonal of fibonacci numbers over [Pascal Triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)

Comment: Unless someone shows super simple method, all can be reduced to efficient and simple sorting vertices and then drawing is not a problem. Maybe You have to create a question for searching such sorting algorithms for diffrent graphs You've presented?

Comment: @Kuba en, One way I'll use and used before is that get coordinates of entries in the graphics of matrix with order, and then obtain the sorting vertices. And you use `ImageSize` to control the fitness of two objects, that's good and simple way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since You have updated question to be more general I'm going to show method which is good to take under consideration as a general approach :)

**one of OP's examples**

First, it is good to set vertices in proper order:

```
dia[1, k_] := Table[{1 + i, (k - i)}, {i, 0, k - 1}] // If[EvenQ@k, Reverse, # &]
mx = {#1, -#2} & @@@Select[
                           Join @@ Table[dia[1, i], {i, 1, 8}],
                           First@# <= 4 \[And] Last@# <= 4 &
                          ]
```

If You don't want to play with `VertexShape` then `Graph` can be a upper layer in `Overlay` with Your `Grid`:

```
graph = Graph[Table[i \[UndirectedEdge] i + 1, {i, 15}],
              VertexCoordinates -> mx, VertexSize -> 0, 
              EdgeStyle -> Directive[{Thick, Red}],
              EdgeShapeFunction -> GraphElementData["FilledArrow"], 
              ImageSize -> {400, 400}, ImagePadding -> 40];

grid = GraphicsGrid[Table[
         Style[StringForm["x[``,``]", a, b], GrayLevel@.6, Bold, 25]
         , {a, 4}, {b, 4}], ImageSize -> 400];

Overlay[{grid, graph}]
```

[image]

```
dia[1, k_] := Table[{1 + i, (k - i)}, {i, 0, k - 1}] // Reverse;
mx = {#1, -#2} & @@@ Select[
                            Join @@ Table[dia[1, i], {i, 1, 8}],
                            First@# <= 4 \[And] Last@# <= 4 &];
```

[image]

---

**General case**

It's about `Graph` and the trick is to set unwanted edges style `Transparent`.

```
mx[a_, b_] :=Table[{{b1, a + 1 - a1},Style[StringForm["x[``,``]", a1, b1], Bold]}, 
                   {a1, a}, {b1, b}] // Flatten[#, 1] &

Graph[Table[i \[UndirectedEdge] i + 1, {i, 24}],
      VertexCoordinates -> mx[5, 5][[ ;; , 1]],
      VertexLabels -> Table[i -> Placed[mx[5, 5][[ i, 2]], Center], {i, 25}], 
      VertexSize -> 0.5, VertexShapeFunction -> "Square",
      EdgeStyle -> (Table[(i \[UndirectedEdge] i + 1) -> Blue, {i, 1, 23, 2}
                         ]~Join~
                    Table[(i \[UndirectedEdge] i + 1) -> Transparent, {i, 2, 24, 2}]),
      EdgeShapeFunction -> GraphElementData["FilledArrow", "ArrowSize" -> .1]]
```

> [image]

Comment: good point---+1

Answer (score 5):

I think this could be an approach:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
length = 5;(*choose here the matrix size!*)img = 
Rasterize@Grid[Table[x[i, j], {i, length}, {j, length}]];
{x, y} = ImageDimensions@img;
listx = x/length*# & /@ Range[0, length];
listy = y/length*# & /@ Range[0, length];
f[i_, j_] := {{0, listy[[i]]}, {listx[[-j]], y}}
temp = MapThread[f, {Range[length], Range[length]}];
img2 = Graphics[{Red, Arrowheads[Medium], Arrow[temp]}, ImageSize -> ImageDimensions@img,
PlotRangePadding -> None, PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> 0, 
AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];
Overlay[{img, img2}]
```

Results:

**5x5 matrix:**

[image]

**6x6 matrix:**

[image]

**7x7 matrix:**

[image]

**8x8 matrix:**

[image]

And so on...

Comment: hi, nice work, maybe you are also interested the more general question.

Comment: @HyperGroups Have you seen [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/visualize-pascals-triangle-and-other-triangle-shaped-lists)?

Comment: ha, I see, thanks, the next goal is to add red lines over Pascal Triangle.