# Visualize Pascal's triangle with the product of the terms in the $n$th row

Tags: graphics, output-formatting, grid-layouts

How to make the  following graphics by using *Mathematica*?

[image: Pascal triangle with products]

**What I tried**:

I used [J.M's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9961/30288) for the Pascal triangle

```
pascal = With[{n = 6}, 
Graphics[Table[
Text[Style[Binomial[n - j, n - i], Large], {2 (i - j/2), 3 j/2}], {i, n}, {j, i}]]]


product = MatrixForm[{1, 1, 2, 9, 96, 2500}
```

then

```
Show[pascal, product]

GraphicsGrid[pascal, product]
```

but it doesn't work.

(sequence 1, 1, 2, 9..  is the product of the terms in the $nth$ row)

Comment: For anybody who wants to take a crack at this: `(j!)^(j - 1)/BarnesG[j + 1]^2` gives the desired product.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Manipulate[

 pascal = Row[Pane[#, 50, Alignment -> Center] & /@ #] & /@ 
   Table[CoefficientList[(x + 1)^i, x], {i, 0, n - 1}];

 product = Pane @ StringPadLeft[ToString[#], 40, "."] & /@ 
   Table[(j!)^(j - 1)/BarnesG[j + 1]^2, {j, 0, n - 1}];

 Grid[{{
    Column[pascal, Center],
    Column[product, Right]
    }}, BaseStyle -> 15]
 ,
 {{n, 6}, 1, 15, 1}]
```

[image]